# jQuery serialize serializes the URL wrong

Tags: php, jquery, encoding, urlencode

I have a form which I submit and I use .serialize to help me gather all data from the form. Now, I've checked in firebug what is sent in POST and I can see a nice formated string like example

```
index.php?data=sth&data2=sth
```

but the problem is with this & in the PHP - the PHP outputs it like this:

```
index.php?data=sth& a m p ;data2=sth
```

See this amp? Well it is written without spaces and it's and encoded (as I found out in google) version of &. So, what should I do to input this url correctly in the database and then fetch it a nd show it on the site without this & amp; ?

edit: if it's possible I would like a string with that & to be put in that format to DB. (so, with & sign).

edit#2:
how I send data:

```
 var formData = $("#myForm :input[value]").serialize();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',                    
     cache:false,
     url: '_ajax/updateGameInfo.php', 
     async: false,                     
     dataType: 'text',
     data: allData,
     success: function(jsonObj) { 
         if (jsonObj){                       
             $msg = 'Data sucessfully updated! Reloading page...';
             alert($msg);
         }
         else{
             $msg = 'Error with the update!';
             alert($msg);
         }   
     }
 });
```

And here is my updateGameInfo.php:

```
$gameRepos = new GameRepository();    

$game = $gameRepos->updateGame();
echo json_encode( $game );
```

And if you also like, here is my updateGame function from GameRepository:

```
public function updateGame()
{
    $cleanPost = array_map( array('GameRepository', 'cleanPostData'), $_POST);
    $attributes = array_keys($cleanPost);
    $values = array_values($cleanPost);      

    $table = $this->resolveTableName( $cleanPost["selectedTypeId"] );
    $id = $cleanPost["selectedGameId"];

    if ($this->openConnection())
    {                                                
        $pairs = "";
        foreach ($cleanPost as $attribute => $value){
            if ($attribute != "selectedGameId" && $attribute != "selectedTypeId"){

            if ($attribute == "url")
                $value = str_replace("amp;", "", $value);    

                $pairs .= $attribute . "='" . $value . "',";
            }    
        }

        $pairs = rtrim($pairs, ','); //remove last comma

        $query = "UPDATE $table SET $pairs WHERE id=$id;";

        $result = pg_query($query);
        if (!$result){
            mysql_error());
            return false;
        }                
        else 
            return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I would answer "just url-decode the string on your server", but I'm not sure what happen in you example. Can you show the code where you generate the string, also how you ouput it and what is in your POST cause what I see here looks like a GET string.

Comment: How do you make your form submit this to your PHP script?

Comment: I am using ajax with jQuery. datatype is text if this has some issue. Btw, I did a stupid hack now and in the php i replaced amp; text with empty string - I know this is bad but if nothing else will help this will have to do... Also, @BiAiB: if the url got encoded somehow, doesn't it make sense that even slashes would be encoded not just & sign? Also, one more thing: I found this link http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/251090 but the fact then is that my url gets encoded and stored like that in the database and I don't want that - cause Ill have to decode it when I'm showing it

Comment: I'd like to see the code for that, since I'm guessing you are doing something wrong on client side when trying to pass your string.

Comment: @Nikola don't do a replace, it's really wrong. Check this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: @Qtax: i updated my post question and now you can see how i send the data.. @BiAiB: if i do urlencode it then whole string gets encoded (also // for exmple), but i don't want that - i want to have it in the database like: http://www.google.com/gameId=1&name=test and not like this: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2FgameId%3D1%26name%3Dtest

Comment: @Nikola, I don't see you use `formData` anywhere in your JS, just `allData`.

Comment: @Qtax: you can assume it's the same (i didn't paste in all of the code - basically allData = formData + someMoreData;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing in the URL as a POST variable, then PHP is going to automatically encode any special characters.  So, assuming the POST variable name is `url`, you would want to do this in your php script before everything else:

```
$_POST['page_url'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['page_url']);
```

The issue isn't with jquery, it's with php.  You'll run into similar issues when passing json strings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the charset in the html header of the page?
Try to change it!